# How do you express the product of three matrices as a weighted sum of outer products?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, outer-product

How do you express the matrix ABC as the weighted sum of outer products of vectors extracted from A and C and with weights coming from matrix B?

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. I tried the outer products of the columns of A with the rows of C, with the entries $B_{ij}$ of the middle matrix serving as the weights. Since B has as many columns as C has rows and as many rows as A has columns, we would have as many outer products in our sum as B has entries. But it didn't work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider the $2 \times 2$ case for the sake of simplicity:

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}t&u\\v&w\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}e&f\\g&h\end{pmatrix}=t\begin{pmatrix}a\\c\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}e&f\end{pmatrix}+u\begin{pmatrix}a\\c\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}g&h\end{pmatrix}+...$$

Indeed, if you denote by $C_1,C_2$ the columns of the first matrix and by $R_1,R_2$ the rows of the 3rd matrix, you just do block products (all with compatible dimensions) like this:

$$\begin{pmatrix}C_1&C_2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}t&u\\v&w\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}R_1\\R_2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}(C_1t+C_2v)&(C_1u+C_2w)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}R_1\\R_2\end{pmatrix}$$

$$=(C_1t+C_2v)R_1+(C_1u+C_2w)R_2=tC_1R_1+vC_2R_1+uC_1R_2+wC_2R_2$$

This process can be extended to any dimensions, not only to $n \times n$ square matrices but more generally to products of rectangular matrices as long as their dimensions are compatible, i.e., with dimensions:

$$(m \times n) \times (n \times p) \times (p \times q)$$

[A similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1869080) asked in the other direction.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? When I try an example, I get different results. $[[1,1],[0,0]] [[1,2],[3,4]], [[1,0],[1,0]] = [[10,0],[0,0]]$ but $1 * [[1],[0]] * [[1,1]] + 2 * [[1],[0]] * [[0,0]] + 3 * [[1],[0]] * [[1,1]] + 4 * [[1],[0]] * [[0,0]] = [[4,4], [0,0]]$

Comment: I am sure (see the edit to my answer). But I will give you an answer about your computation.

Comment: You haven't taken the **rows** of the 3rd matrix : it should be $1∗[[1],[0]]∗[[1,\color{red}{0}]]+2∗[[1],[0]]∗[[\color{red}{1},0]]+3∗[[1],[0]]∗[[\color{red}{1},0]]+4∗[[1],[0]]∗[[\color{red}{1},0]$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I think I see how to prove the general case now. Btw, there's a typo in your $2 \times 2$ example. The row vectors on the right hand side are the transposed columns of the 3rd matrix, when they should have been its rows. I will accept your answer once you confirm this.

Comment: You are right! Sorry. I correct it.